# What is the closest native code development/debugging experience you can get for Javascript/HTML5/CSS on Mac?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, html, firebug

I've been a developer for a long time and I've been in and out of web development for years. As far as I know this is an elusive question. Lately I have developing in Xcode in Objective-C and am seeking a development environment that as closely resembles that experience (Xcode), in terms of modern IDE features like a debugger with breakpoints, inspection, code completion/intellisense, etc.

I have done some JS development before using Text editors/Firebug, but I do not think this is adequate. Javascript is flakey in general and I'm looking for a more quality experience, a comprehensive development environment (for Mac) that will provide a great experience for developing HTML5 / CSS3 / Javascript (with libraries such as JQuery) / AJAX apps.

Can anyone with time spent enduring the suffrage of Javascript development and debugging point me in the right direction for tools to make this experience better? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, can't help with suggestions for the Mac, but I just wanted to comment that JavaScript isn't flaky. Though I've worked with a few JavaScript coders who would write flaky code in _any_ language. (I'm not implying that you're one of them.)

Comment: I like the WebStorm IDE from The IntelliJ folks. It has loads of intelligence built in to it. For JavaScript debugging specifically, the built-in debugger on most modern browsers (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox) works great.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, I noticed that earlier and was going to check it out, I'm currently trying to evaluate Aptana. @nnnnnn I disagree I guess. JS will let you shoot yourself really easily imo, and like, if you screw up anywhere, your script just stops executing, and dies silently. Thats flakey and pretty BS, no two ways about it.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm happy to agree to disagree. Dying silently can be good for the end-users though, because they don't want to be seeing a bunch of error messages, whereas for the developer a JS console is generally enough to see all the errors, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn Are you aware of any tool or environment that will provide a "compile time check" on your JS code, similar to what a native compiler would do, even though JS is not compiled? Thats something I am really looking for.

Comment: Not for the Mac, but I'm not a Mac guy so I've never looked. If you look into http://jshint.com/ and http://jslint.com/ I believe both have options for integration into some IDEs, so maybe there is a Mac option.

Answer (score 1):

I would try Dashcode. It's the best IDE I've seen for front-end web development on Mac, it's free, and it includes a separate editor for mobile sites, if you need that. Hopefully it works well for your purposes.

Comment: For "a development environment that closely resembles [Xcode's] experience", Dashcode seems to be the best bet, seeing as it's part of Apple's developer tools.

Comment: Yeah I was about to check it out, but wasn't sure what kind of support there is in there for debugging executing JS and syntax checking / code analysis. Do you think you can use it to easily and effectively develop and debug a mobile site built with say... HTML5 boilerplate and JQuery Mobile?

Comment: Well I know you it has support for setting breakpoints graphically, and for the most part functions the same way as Xcode in this respect (including syntax highlighting/code analysis). I am not sure about how it integrates external libraries though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing Frontend related stuff for several years on Mac now and I fall in love with *codA* from *panic software* as IDE.

http://panic.com/coda/

Comment: Yeah I've been aware of it for quite a while. Its expensive considering there seems to be a few free solutions available. How would you describe the development experience for authoring a mobile web app using HTML5 boilerplate and JQuery Mobile. Can you get syntax checking on your JS? Do you need to resort to Firebug to debug its execution? Thx!